# OpenNebula: instantiate a service template with Curl providing a service name

Tags: curl, opennebula

In OpenNebula 5.4, I am able to instantiate a Service from a Service Template using Curl, but I don't know how to provide a service name.
The [website example](https://docs.opennebula.org/5.4/integration/system_interfaces/appflow_api.html#instantiate-a-given-template) works as expected:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:2474/service_template/4/action -u 'oneadmin:opennebula' -v -X POST --data '{
  "action": {
    "perform":"instantiate"
  }
}'
```

Creates a service, with the same name than the service template.
But if I run the same trying to add a parameter for  that instantiate `action` (as done when [performing an action on a given service](https://docs.opennebula.org/5.4/integration/system_interfaces/appflow_api.html#perform-an-action-on-a-given-service)), for example:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:2474/service_template/4/action -u 'oneadmin:opennebula' -v -X POST --data '{
  "action": {
    "perform":"instantiate", 
    "params" : { 
       "name" : "new_name" 
     }
  }
}'
```

It ignores that param, resulting in the same as when running the previously mentioned Website example... I tried with 'name', 'service-name', 'service_name', but same result...
Do you know how to do that, please? I think it probably is supported ([as it is in their Java API](https://archives.opennebula.org/doc/3.6/oca/java/org/opennebula/client/template/Template.html#instantiate(org.opennebula.client.Client,%20int,%20java.lang.String))), but not documented (as many other features).

In advance, thanks a lot and cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the office we found a workaround:

it looks like it's not yet supported to send the parameter, so, it has to be performed a posterior action to update the newly created service, using the new Service ID (the full service JSON is returned in the body of the previous request):
E.g: if the new service instantiated has ID 85, it would be:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:2474/service/85/action -u 'oneadmin:opennebula' -v -X POST --data '{
"action": {
  "perform": "rename",
  "params": {
    "name": "some-service-name"
  }
 }
}'
```